# show coordinates on plot using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, coordinate-systems

I'm sorry, I can't seem to find how to do this. This works, but I would love to have the coordinates plotted along the axis:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new('RGBA', (250, 250), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle([(0, 0), (249, 249)], outline='black')  # just here to create a visible box
draw.rectangle([(10, 40), (100, 200)], fill='red', outline='red')
im
```

[image]

Does anyone have any advice? Just would love to see numbers along the vertical and horizontal components of the plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "brute force" way to do this. You could generalize it to better handle different x/y ranges. Maybe you could use matplotlib and potentially go off [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/errorbars_and_boxes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbars-and-boxes-py)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new('RGBA', (250, 250), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle([(0, 0), (249, 249)], outline='black')  # just here to create a visible box
draw.rectangle([(10, 40), (100, 200)], fill='red', outline='red')
# Draw x ticks
[draw.line(((x,250),(x,245)),fill='black') for x in range(0,249,5)]
# Draw x labels
[draw.text((x,235),str(x),fill='black')for x in range(0,249,25)]
# Can do same for y...
im
```

[image: Very basic example]

Comment: nice! ugly...but nice!